# How to import an old Excel file with extension.xls?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file from SAS that is exported as an older Excel .xls file.  I would like to import this file into python 3.5.

when I do:

```
import pandas as pd
Filewant = pd.read_excel("Filepath\\\Filename.xls")
```

I get a bunch of error messages culminating in

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<html xm'
```

if I open up the file and manually save it in a current .xlsx file and us the same command line using:

Filewant =pd.read_excel("Filepath\\Filename\.xlsx")

then the file is imported into Python properly. However, I want the process to be more automated so I don't to have to manually save the file to .xlsx format to make it work.

Comment: As an alternative, have you tried `ExcelFile.parse()`? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html

Comment: Just checking - your SAS-derived file is definitely native xls, and not some kind of HTML export labelled as xls?

Comment: Use the `openpyxl` module. `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')`. An example of this can be seen at https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: The old `xls` format does not use XML at all, so that error message leads me to believe that is not a true Excel (xls) file, as @TimWilliams hits on.

Answer (score 2):

SAS tech support told me that this won't work and that I'll need to convert the .xls SAS output into a .xlsx file:

Unfortunately, the MSOffice2K destination creates an HTML file even though it uses the .XLS extension here which allows the file to be opened with excel. 
You can use VBScript to convert the file to .XLSX, however, there is no way to do this using the MSoffice2K destination.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the problem. `found b'<html xm'` Your file is an HTML file and not an XLS file. This was commonly done with "old" SAS since it did not support writing XLS files, but Excel did support reading HTML files.

Comment: So, is there anything I can do? I tried openpxyl.load_workbook("FilePath") and got an error: 
InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format., So I used xlrd.open_workbook("FilePath") and got the following error: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<html xm'

Comment: It is an HTML file not an EXCEL file. You need to use a function that can read an HTML file.